# Шорткод product_category, как сортировать по цене?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Использую код [product_category category="категория"] для вывода товаров из определенной категории на странице, но они по умолчанию сортируются по названию, что необходимо добавить, чтобы сортировалось по цене? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Для сортировки по цене надо добавить следующий фильтр в `functions.php` вашей темы.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby' );

function woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby( $args ) {

    $standard_array = array('menu_order','title','date','rand','id');

    if( isset( $args['orderby'] ) && !in_array( $args['orderby'], $standard_array ) ) {
        $args['meta_key'] = $args['orderby'];
        $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num'; 
    }

    return $args;
}
```